# How to change email in top-info class in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have to change email in preheader class top-info like you can see on this pic:
[see prt sc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqfRO.jpg)

I did not work on this website so i can't find where to change this email.

Where in code in Wordpress could be that or have to change email with some trick maybe with javascript/jquery.

I have found this in header.php:

`<a href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr($pix_options['pix_email_address'])?>"><?php echo esc_attr($pix_options['pix_email_address'])?></a>`

How to change that?

Website: http://pravneresitve.si/

Email has to change from info@pravnik.si to info@pravneresitve.si (name of domene).

Comment: you maybe find it in the `apperances>customize` or you can check it in the `header.php` file in your theme folder

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: I have found this in header.php:
<a href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr($pix_options['pix_email_address'])?>"><?php echo esc_attr($pix_options['pix_email_address'])?></a> 
How to change that?

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is find in wordpress admin options and replace the email. Otherwise you can use like this script.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".top-info").find("a").text("info@pravneresitve.si").attr("href","mailto:info@pravneresitve.si");
  });
```

Comment: This did not work so i found this in php header: <a href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr($pix_options['pix_email_address'])?>"><?php echo esc_attr($pix_options['pix_email_address'])?></a>     How to change that to right email

Answer (score 0):

Change that email using jQuery *.text()* method and *.attr()* to change the HTML href attribute:

```
$(".top-info a").text(function () {
    return $(this).attr("href","info@pravneresitve.si").text().replace("info@pravnik.si", "info@pravneresitve.si");
});
```

But the best thing is to change it from php in header.php. You try to look in **WordPress dashboard -> Appearance -> Customize**. Here in the right menu you can find that email in Header.

Comment: I have found this in header.php:
<a href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr($pix_options['pix_email_address'])?>"><?php echo esc_attr($pix_options['pix_email_address'])?></a> 
How to change that?